# Simulating Case-Control-Covariate Data

Tags: simulation, case-control-study

I generate data with a covariate $Y_1$ and disease liability $Y_2$ using the following model:

$\begin{pmatrix}Y_1\\Y_2\end{pmatrix} \sim \mathcal{N}\left( \begin{pmatrix}\mathbf{X}\beta_1\\\mathbf{X}\beta_2\end{pmatrix}, \mathbf{\Sigma} \right)$

There is a threshold $t$ and say that everyone with $Y_2 > t$ is a "case" and everyone with $Y_2 \leqslant t$ is a "control."

I want to create some test data such that the distribution of the covariate in the cases $(Y_1 | Y_2 > t)$ is as similar as possible to the distribution of the covariate in the control $(Y_1 | Y_2 \leqslant t)$.

As $\beta_1$ increases in magnitude, the difference between the cases and controls becomes more pronounced, and even for relatively small values of $\beta_1$, I can't generate any cases with the lowest values for their covariate without an astronomical amount of sampling.

At really big values of $\beta_1$, this problem separates from reality and becomes infeasible, because you'll be sampling a tiny tail of low-covariate cases and high-covariate controls, but it's as yet been impractical at very small values of $\beta_1$.

I originally tried to get the case and control covariate distributions to fit the population distribution by doing rejection sampling on a histogram. That worked for $\beta_1 = 0$, but has failed for pretty much everything else.

At this point, I'd be happy if the cases and controls at least had the same (expected) mean covariate value, but I'm not sure what the best way is to reject individuals based on their $Y_1$ status. Actually peeking at the $Y_1$ values and then throwing away the highest ones feels like cheating, so I think I need an *a priori* function to determine which samples to keep and which to throw away.

Comment: When you "generate test data" do you need to keep the matrix $X$ fixed or are you allowed to vary its components?  The former case looks difficult to deal with while the latter case may require you to specify a distribution for $X$ or at least bounds on the values that can appear in each column.

Comment: $X$ is not fixed--I generate lots of $X$'s, produce $Y$'s according to the distribution at the top, and then reject samples that don't fit.

Comment: What can you tell us about the distribution of the $X$'s (or, better yet, the joint distribution of $(X,Y)$)?

Comment: Ah, does it matter?  I'm simulating genetic data, so X represents the number of copies of each SNP. For simplicity, you can assume that it's an $Nx1$ vector of independent Bernoulli rvs that have been shifted to mean zero. Then the distribution of the Y's then given by the equation at the top.

Comment: It matters tremendously: if you don't have any limitations on $X$, you will be fine--and the solution is an easy one--but otherwise a solution (that works efficiently and has predictable properties) may be difficult or almost impossible to come up with.